# how to use ng-bind (one way binding) in form inputs properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I noticed that if I change the value of input2  manually and then change values of input1,  the value of input 2 will not updated any more, why? is it to say the one-way binding will be broken in the form inputs if the user typing something in it?

```
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        1: <input name="input1"  ng-model="topValue"/>
        2: <input name="input2"  value="{{topValue}}"/>
        topValue: <span>{{topValue}}</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `ngValue` doesn't support **`input[text]`**

From [ngValue docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngValue):

> Binds the given expression to the value of **input[select]** or **input[radio]**, so that when the element is selected, the ngModel of that element is set to the bound value.

---

I debugged [ngValue](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngValue) when using with  `input[text]`:

- Look in `ngValueDirective` ([input.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js))
- The $watch callback was invoked when **input1** changed.
- `attr.$set('value',value);` only changes the **inner-editor** (look below)
- I replaced it with `elm[0].value = value || "";` and it works:

---

[image: $set]

---

```js
var ngValueDirective = function() {
  return {
    priority: 100,
    compile: function(tpl, tplAttr) {
      if (CONSTANT_VALUE_REGEXP.test(tplAttr.ngValue)) {
        return function ngValueConstantLink(scope, elm, attr) {
          attr.$set('value', scope.$eval(attr.ngValue));
        };
      } else {
        return function ngValueLink(scope, elm, attr) {
          scope.$watch(attr.ngValue, function valueWatchAction(value) {
            //attr.$set('value', value);
            elm[0].value = value || "";
          });
        };
      }
    }
  };
};
```

#### When you interpolate with `value` (or any other attribute) :

- angular creates `$observe` in `addAttrInterpolateDirective` function ([compile.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js))
- When the `$observe` callback is invoked it uses `attr.$set(name, newValue)`, same issue;

#### Conclusion -

- Either [file a feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues)
- Or implement your own `ngValue` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When user edits value of input2 then input2's value is no longer an expression that angularjs can understand therefore changes to *topValue* are not reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: The binding works.

Long Version:

There is a difference between the attributes of an element and its properties. This is particularly true for attributes of an `input` element.

The `value` attribute is the **initial** or default value of the element. As soon as you type something into the `input` field, `value` doesn't matter anymore.

So when you use an angular expression like `value="{{topValue}}"`, the value of the attribute will change whenever then expression `{{topValue}}` changes. But it simply doesn't matter as soon as you change the content of the `input` field. Either manually or even programmatically by setting the `value` **property** of the `input` element.